# 16.04: Just cant figure out where did i go wrong with my LAMP and wordpress installation

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, apache2, lamp, wordpress

I have installed and reinstalled LAMP+Wordpress, but when i check it on my browser it is not working. I have tried almost everything, as i don't know what exactly to do.
When i go to 127.0.0.1 it says: Error establishing a database connection.
Is this happening because i dont have a server version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
or
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Now check your 127.0.0.1 
These were the steps to install a LAMP server.
Intermediate steps are there where you need to choose a username and password for mysql. Note them down.

Comment: hi thanks! after typing "sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5", it gives the following error:
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36789471/6091876

This may help :) Accept the answer if useful

Comment: I am sorry it did not help

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 
Try this

Comment: even that didnt help

Comment: Then, I guess you Downloaded some corrupt packages. Try apt-get purge to remove all the existing components and do a fresh install

Comment: Could you please give me a step by step method to remove these packages as I cant find a method that works for me.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/531118

Comment: thanks I have tried that but i have some other version of php and after the second one it says:


sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2; rm -rf /etc/php5; rm -rf /var/lib/mysql; rm etc/mysql
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'etc/mysql': No such file or directory

Comment: Permission denied means you have to give "sudo" before every command and for the second one use rm -rf etc/mysql because it is a folder. (-r stands for recursive delete all the files of a folder)

Comment: I have been using sudo for every command....it still says that

Answer (score 0):

By default, on a fresh installation, Apache does not need a database to run.
Check your default document root directory  (`/var/www/html` in Ubuntu), there must be only one file (`index.html`).

Comment: hi. i am sorry. i am just a beginner. I hope i am not doing anything wrong but when i write it in the command prompt all it says is: "it is a directory" how should i check what it contains

Comment: Type `ls /var/www/html` in your terminal

Comment: thanks. I have many wordpress files there:

    index.php        wp-admin              wp-cron.php        wp-settings.php
info.php         wp-blog-header.php    wp-includes        wp-signup.php
license.txt      wp-comments-post.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-trackback.php
readme.html      wp-config.php         wp-load.php        xmlrpc.php
wordpress        wp-config-sample.php  wp-login.php
wp-activate.php  wp-content            wp-mail.php


what should i do?

Comment: That means there is not a problem with Apache. Your Wordpress installation was not done properly. The main problem is with your `wp-config.php` file, try to edit this file with the appropriate information (MySQL server, Database and so on).

Comment: Thanks i will reinstall it but even before i downloaded wordpress my apache2 wasnt working